# C# Regex Match gives wrong result

Tags: c#, regex

```
 var hostName = "tenant1.example.be";

 var match = Regex.Match(hostName, @"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.example\.be$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 var subdomain = match.Success ? match.Value : null;
```

Result for subdomain is always: `tenant1.example.be` instead of just `tenant1`.

Anyone?

Comment: The regex works perfectly. You are extracting the entire matching value, not the captured group

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a bug in the conditional or assignment operators instead?

Comment: Why have `A-Za-z` and `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`?

Comment: You may use `var subdomain = match.Groups[1].Value ?? string.Empty;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need only the first group of the match:

```
var subdomain = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
```

Comment: Actually you'll want match.Groups[1].Value.

Comment: Of course! Damn it has been a long time using this Regex. Thanks mate